# How to make the shadow fade in (css stylesheet for html)

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so when somebody hovers over a button, some glow fades in. I tried that with this code:

```
     .discord_join_button:hover{
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        box-shadow: 0 0px 60px #2332d8;
        animation-duration: 500ms;
    }
```

for some reason this isn't working and the box-shadow just pops into existence

I was expecting it to fade, not just show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve the "fade in" effect by specifying the `transition` property to the `button` base style. For example:

```css
.discord_join_button {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.discord_join_button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px #2332d8; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Transition</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="discord_join_button">Hover me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to know more about the `transition` property: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: i don't know if you would know, but it would be great if you could try and answer this too?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496445/how-to-make-a-box-shadow-bigger-without-making-the-fog-effect-weaker

Comment: Hi, I cannot answer or comment under that question for some reason I don't know. However I suggest you to read about the `box-shadow` property and experiment a little bit with since I don't have that much experience with it. Here are some useful links: [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), [Css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/)

Answer (score 0):

```
     .discord_join_button{
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        box-shadow: 0 0px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0);
        transition: 500ms;
    }

     .discord_join_button:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0px 60px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    }
```

Use rgba.
And transition should be applied before hover.

I don't know if it's what you want, but if you write the box-shadow value in reverse, it's also possible to make it work in reverse.